# "Database does not exist" error when connecting from Python despite other database connections working

Tags: python, mysql, azure, phpmyadmin

I am trying to establish a connection to a database so that I can run SQL queries from Python. I have four database files in the same directory, and I can connect to all but one of them. What could possibly be the difference when I'm only replacing the name of the database?

Comment: They're all via the same connection parameters, host, user, password etc?  And you're sure there are no typos?  Beyond that more details would be needed.  Show some code/some additional info about your database.  What version of MySQL are you using and what version of python?  Does your last database name use any special characters using properly in python? What library are you using to connect?  I know you're new here so a general good rule is to always give the version of everything that you're using.  Helps narrow down the search and can help find answers.

Comment: "*four database files in the same directory*" ... this makes it sound like you are *not* using MySQL, but are referring to something other than MySQL. Absent more information, or example of the code that is throwing the error, we are just guessing.... https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @bjk116 That helped steer me in the right direction. Thanks. It looks like the database exists in phpMyAdmin (which is where I end up if I click on "Manage" under "MySQL in App" on Azure)... but it is not in the list of resources in "Azure Database for MySQL server."

Comment: Please add this as an answer and close this thread by accepting it.It will help other who have the same problem